# Get-FolderItem version to get all folders

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have found a cmdlet that returns all files regardless of path size. I was wondering if there was an equivalent command that got all the folders regardless of path size?

[`Get-FolderItem`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Deeply-Nested-Files-a2148fd7) combines robocopy and powershell to return all files even those with the path greater than 260.

Is there anyway to get all the folders in the fileshare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-FolderItem` uses the `robocopy` switch `/NDL` to exclude directories from the log output, which it uses to grab the file info. It also avoids empty folders by using the `/S` switch to recurse rather than `/E`

Simply change the `$params` variable from:

```
$params.AddRange(@("/L","/S","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NC","/NDL","/TS","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0"))
```

to

```
$params.AddRange(@("/L","/E","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NC","/NFL","/TS","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0"))
```

Now, Robocopy will list directories, rather than files. Since the output for directories is a little different from files, you'll have to change the parsing logic a bit as well.

Change

```
If ($_.Trim() -match "^(?<Size>\d+)\s(?<Date>\S+\s\S+)\s+(?<FullName>.*)") {
    $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ParentFolder = $matches.fullname -replace '(.*\\).*','$1'
        FullName = $matches.FullName
        Name = $matches.fullname -replace '.*\\(.*)','$1'
        Length = [int64]$matches.Size
        LastWriteTime = [datetime]$matches.Date
        Extension = $matches.fullname -replace '.*\.(.*)','$1'
        FullPathLength = [int] $matches.FullName.Length
    }
    $object.pstypenames.insert(0,'System.IO.RobocopyDirectoryInfo')
    Write-Output $object
}
```

to

```
If ($_.Trim() -match "^(?<Children>\d+)\s+(?<FullName>.*)") {
    $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ParentFolder = $matches.fullname -replace '(.*\\).*','$1'
        FullName = $matches.FullName
        Name = $matches.fullname -replace '.*\\(.*)','$1'
    }
    $object.pstypenames.insert(0,'System.IO.RobocopyDirectoryInfo')
    Write-Output $object
}
```

And that should do it